# approach ideas for a simple dashboard interface

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I recently started with rails and now I am at the point where I need a bit of help in understanding how I can combine different views in one view controller. In my test page I have the following parts:

- ModelA
- ModelB
- User
  ModelA, ModelB, User have their controllers and their views (new and edit as partial view, show).
  ModelA and ModelB belong to User.

Now I want to have a Dashboard where the user can see more details information about the models he created. Also it should be possible to edit or delete the models he created. 
But here it's where I am having the problems.

I created a controller for the Dashboard. There I have the index view where I render the partial for modelA and modelB. `<%= render @modelA %>` and in the navigation of the dashboard I have a link to an detailed show_modelA.html.erb where I render with `<%= render :partial => "modelA/modelA_detailed", :collection => @modelA_detailed %>` .

As you can see the partials still are in the view of modelA. 
But which is the best way? Now I am getting problems showing the edit forms for modelA because I don't know how to connect them from the view to the dashboard controller. In the partial for modelA I create the links to edit the entry `<%= link_to "edit", edit_modelA_path(modelA.id) %>`

If i want now that these actions go from the dashboard, I have to change the path to a dashboard path? Or put in the edit.html.erb from modelA the navbar (shared/navbar) from the dashboard ?

Or another approach like in [filling the layout](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/filling_in_the_layout) where the application controller uses yield to insert the content of each page?

I hope it is possible to understand what I am trying to do. If someone has some advices feel free to answer.

Thank you.

// EDIT
I think I got the solution for me. If someone knows something to improve or to change it would be nice to tell.

Now I have the following structure inside my app folder:

- controllers/dashboard/modelA_controller.rb
- controllers/dashboard/modelB_controller.rb
- controllers/dashboard/users_controller.rb
- controllers/dashboard_controller.rb
- controllers/modleA_controller.rb
- controllers/modelB_controller.rb
- controllers/users_controller.rb

the controllers inside the dashboard inherit from their controllers in the controllers folder. All the logic for edit and delete moved inside these dashboard controllers. 
The app/views folder has the same strucure as the controllers one. All html.erb files for edit and delete moved to the dashboard folder inside the specific folder.
I think this is a good approach/solution for this. There is no code reused.
In the routes.rb file I had to add some routes:

```
namespace :dashboards do
  resources :users
  resources :modelAs
  resources :modelBs
end
```

Comment: Could you provide some screenshots so it is easier to understand what you want to achieve?

Comment: Here I put like some of the uses cases.
[dashboard with modelAs][2]

[dashboard with editModelA][3]

[dashboard with extra info modelA][4]

[model without dashboard like other users should see it outside from dashboard][5]


  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3WzV.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHVsp.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8dsT.png
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4cqh.png

Comment: Sounds like you want a multitenant app. Do some searches on multitenancy and rails.

Comment: I just added my solution in my question. I think it works for me. But if someone would change something tell me. Thanks